# How to use `date_select` with `:use_month_names`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `date_select`. It has default months (January, February etc.). I want to change it, and add custom months (Ukraine month). I found an option for this, but I don't understand how it works.

This is my attempt:

```
 <%= ht.date_select :data, :start_year => Date.current.year, 
 :use_month_names => {January: 'Січень',                                                                                
 :February => 'Лютий', :March => 'Березень', :April => 'Квітень',                                                                                    
:May => 'Травень', :June => 'Червень', :July => 'Липень', :August => 
  'Серпень',                                                                                    
  :September => 'Вересень', :October => 'Жовтень', :November => 
  'Листопад', :December => 'Грудень' } %>
```

How does this option `:use_month_names` work?

Comment: I find answer: don`t use hash, user default array ["name 1st month", "name 2st month", etc] sorry guys, i am freshman)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) it seems you have to pass an array with those names. Try

```
<%= ht.date_select :data, :start_year => Date.current.year, 
 :use_month_names => ['Січень', 'Лютий', 'Березень','Квітень', 'Травень', 'Червень', 'Липень', 'Серпень', 'Вересень', 'Жовтень', 'Листопад', 'Грудень'] %>
```

Comment: TY!!! as soon as I created the question I immediately found the answer. However, let this issue exist, since someone can also confuse and will create not a simple array and not a hash)